# Using time_diff to displays remaining days/hours/minutes/seconds in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, date-format

I'm using the `time_diff` gem in a Rails 4 application. I want to show how many days/hours/minutes/seconds are left between the `created_at` field and `created_at + 7.days`.

```
Time.diff(@auction.created_at + 7.days, @auction.created_at, '%d %H %N %S')[:diff]
```

Output:

```
7 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds
```

How can I get a result like:

```
7d 0h 0m 0s
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did my answer helper?

Answer (score 1):

As per their documentation, you can use `%h %m %s` instead of `%H %N %S`

documentation extract:

```
%h - hour (without adding 'hour' text to the hours. eg: 3 for 3 hours)
%m - minute (without adding 'minute' text)
%s - second (without adding 'second' text)
```

So your code should be

```
Time.diff(@auction.created_at + 7.days, @auction.created_at, '%d %hh %mm %ss')[:diff]
```

Now for the day you need to use a i18n yaml file

```
en:
  day: "d"
```